# Laravel eloquent join three table

Tags: php, laravel, inner-join, eloquent

I am new to [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). Now i need some help on join table eloquent.

Here is my table structure,

**Product Table**

```
product_id    product_code    product_name
     1            1434            ABC
```

**Product History Table**

```
history_id    product_id    cost    invoice_number
    1              1        100         ABC-01
```

**Product Tour Table**

```
tour_id       product_id    provider_name
    1              1            TEST
```

Now i join these 3 table,

```
$product =  product::join('product_history as ph', 'product.product_id', '=', 'ph.product_id', 'inner')
            ->join('product_tour as pt', 'product.product_id', '=', 'pt.product_id', 'inner')
            ->where('product.product_id', '1')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```

It is working properly. But i think Laravel also provide **Eloquent Relationship**. Like, `hasOne`, `hasMany`, `belongsTo`, `belongsToMany` etc....

> Any idea which method is use for my structure ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your query like this :

```
$product =  product::Select("*")
            //->with('product_history','product_tour')
            //Use this with() for condition.
            ->with([
                   'ProductHistory' => function ($query){
                                    $query->select('*');
                   },
                   'ProductTour' => function ($query) use ($ProviderName) {
                                    $query->select('*')->where("provider_name", "=", $ProviderName);
                   },
            ])
            ->where('product.product_id', '1')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```

Here is the code for model file:

```
namespace App;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function producthistory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductHistory', 'product_id','history_id');        
    }
    public function producttour()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductTour', 'product_id','tour_id');        
    }

}
```

And model files for the other tables named as `Product_history` and `product_tour`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductHistory extends Model
{    

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'history_id','product_id');
    }

}
```

And

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductTour extends Model
{    

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'tour_id','product_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes i need to set the relationship.

Comment: Okay thank you. Can you explain why hasMany method use ?

Comment: HasMany relationship states that for every product there are many entries in the `product_history` as well as in the `product_tour` table.In case if they are having only one entry then you can use `hasOne` relationship

Comment: @JaydeepMor More information can be found at this link : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158570/discussion-between-ketan-solanki-and-jaydeep-mor).